# Finding $a^{2014} + b^{2014} + c^{2014}$ given some conditions on $a,b,c$.

Tags: linear-algebra, recreational-mathematics, systems-of-equations

I came across this problem:

"Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be nonzero real numbers that satisfy the conditions :

$$a + b + c = 9,\\\mathrm{and}~ab + bc + ca = 27
$$
Calculate

$$a^{2014} + b^{2014} + c^{2014}."$$

Comment: Note that $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ca$.  Then, ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2= 2(a+b+c)^2-6(ab+bc+ca)=0$$

Comment: I need another hint pls...

Comment: @TheMagicalMachine what can you say about a sum of squares equal to zero ?